# Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET ....'

Tags: google-plus

I have [a small card game for Google+](http://preferans.de/google/) which needs the visitor's name, avatar, gender and city.

It works for myself, but in the error_log I see a lot of PHP-exceptions:

```
[28-Jan-2012 19:06:33] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAgQl0UeNM553PfLnPmP0jTtcJ8ZIQ3q0g: (404) Not Found' in /var/www/html/preferans.de/google/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php:86
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/preferans.de/google/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php(56): apiREST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(apiHttpRequest))
#1 /var/www/html/preferans.de/google/google-api-php-client/src/service/apiServiceResource.php(151): apiREST::execute(Object(apiServiceRequest))
#2 /var/www/html/preferans.de/google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiPlusService.php(207): apiServiceResource->__call('get', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/preferans.de/google/index.php(33): PeopleServiceResource->get('me')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/preferans.de/google/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php on line 86
```

Here is my script:

```
<?php

require_once('google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php');
require_once('google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiPlusService.php');

session_start();

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName('Video-Preferans');
$client->setClientId('XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('XXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://preferans.de/google');
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXX');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        $me = $plus->people->get('me'); # XXX line 33 XXX
        # the access token may have been updated lazily
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
        printf('
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<p><a href="%s">Play Preferans</a></p>
</body>
</html>
', $client->createAuthUrl());
        exit();
}

$viewer_id = $me['id'];
list($first_name, $last_name) = explode(' ', $me['displayName']);
$city      = $me['placesLived'][0]['value'];
$female    = ($me['gender'] == 'male' ? 0 : 1);
$avatar    = $me['image']['url'];

....skipped some html code....
```

Does anybody please know, why the **apiServiceException** is being thrown?

Or how and where at least catch it, so that I can debug it better?

I'm using [the latest Google+ SDK 0.4.8.3](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) and also I'm requesting very basic user information and as I've written - it works for me and also for my wife's account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap $me = $plus->people->get('me') within a try/catch block.

The plus/v1/people/me API returns a 404 Not Found when the user hasn't registered for Google+, and you can catch this case with the following:

```
try {
   $me = $plus->people->get('me')
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  // Handle exception. You can also catch Exception here.
  // You can also get the error code from $e->getCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, only difference is I'm trying to use the Calendar API. I get the exact same error response as you did in the first place, tried the try/catch-block and it kind of worked. If I print the error response it says "403", but I also get the JSON-response I want. Do you know why?

my code:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    try{
        $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');
        print 'Your Activities: <pre>' . print_r($activities, true) . '</pre>';

        // The access token may have been updated.
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
      // Handle exception. You can also catch Exception here.
      // You can also get the error code from $e->getCode();
        echo $e->getCode();
        print_r($activities);
    }

}
```

Comment: when i try doing the above i get a 403 error. what does that mean ?